# シノニムは設定されているが投稿がないという場合に /tags/**/synonyms が404になる

Tags: バグ, タグ

[タグシノニムの一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest)でマスター側のタグをクリックすると、そのタグのシノニム一覧（/tags/**/synonyms）が表示されますが、そのタグが付けられた投稿が一つもない場合に404が表示されます。

例 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/media-player/synonyms

前述の一覧ページからリンクされているのですから、投稿がなくても /tags/**/synonyms を表示するべきではないでしょうか。

---

If you click on a parent tag from the [tag synonym list](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) then you get a list of the synonyms (`/tags/**/synonyms`), but if there are no posts tagged with a tag, you get a 404 instead.

Example: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/media-player/synonyms

Since these tags are displayed on the tag synonym list, they shouldn't default to a 404 even if there isn't a post tagged with that tag currently.

Comment: 何がどう不自然なのかわかるように文章を大幅に変更しました。もし質問意図に沿わない内容になってしまっていましたら、お手数ですが修正いただくか、その旨をご指摘ください。

Comment: @unalistそうそう、そんな感じです。

Comment: 日本語SOだけではなく、他のサイトでも同じようになるみたいですね。[Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app-inventor/synonyms)